MutableStateMapOf cannot be wrapped in rememberSaveable?
I want to initialize an observable map using an existing map.  I tried
val myMap by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(otherMap) }

otherMap is a MutableMap<MyEnum, Boolean>.  It crashed "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MutableState containing androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateMap cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation only supports types which can be stored inside the Bundle."
I tried
val myMap by rememberSaveable { mutableStateMapOf<MyEnum, Boolean>(otherMap) } 

and it fails to compile.  I need myMap to be mutable ie
myMap[key] = value


Does this answer your question? Using rememberSaveable with mutableStateListOf -- It won't tell you how to use rememberSaveable on a mutableStateMapOf, but it does tell you that you shouldn't even do this to start with. Which applies to your situation, since you already have the data in otherMap which, hopefully, comes from the view model. Don't duplicate the values in Compose, just change them in the view model.

Does this answer your question? Using rememberSaveable with mutableStateListOf

Yep, I appreciate your reply tyg and am going to put it in my vm.

I think you should create your own composable to mirror the logic of rememberSaveable function
@Composable
fun <K : Any, V : Any> rememberMutableStateMapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>): SnapshotStateMap<K, V> {
    return rememberSaveable(saver = snapshotStateMapSaver()) {
        pairs.toList().toMutableStateMap()
    }
}

private fun <K : Any, V : Any> snapshotStateMapSaver() = listSaver<SnapshotStateMap<K, V>, Pair<K, V>>(
    save = { stateMap -> stateMap.toList() },
    restore = { it.toMutableStateMap() }
)

Then invoke it as you would normally:
val expandedStates = rememberMutableStateMapOf<String,Boolean>()

Hope that helps!
